# Where can i find the right version of sparkxgb.zip for the xgboost4j-1.1.2.jar package for Pyspark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, xgboost

I was using `xgboost4j-0.90.jar` in `Pyspark` alongside its working version of `sparkxgb.zip`. Everything was working well till i decided to update to `xgboost4j-1.1.2.jar`. Since i'm using `scala 2.11` and i can't change the `scala` version for other reasons, the most updated version of `xgboost4j` i could get that was compatible with `scala 2.11` was `xgboost4j-1.1.2`.

The problem i found now is that when on `Pyspark` i want to build a model using the `XGBoostClassifier()` class i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-56249c4ed3fb> in <module>()
----> 1 XGBoostClassifier()

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p0.6626826/lib/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    108             raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__)
    109         self._input_kwargs = kwargs
--> 110         return func(self, **kwargs)
    111     return wrapper
    112 

/tmp/spark-da5b0f7f-7899-450b-a3bc-f9359c37ac9c/userFiles-805b892a-61df-41ed-83eb-b7127f3f7765/sparkxgb.zip/sparkxgb/xgboost.py in __init__(self, alpha, baseMarginCol, baseScore, checkpointInterval, checkpointPath, colsampleBylevel, colsampleBytree, contribPredictionCol, customEval, customObj, eta, evalMetric, featuresCol, gamm, growPolicy, labelCol, reg_lambda, lambdaBias, leafPredictionCol, maxBin, maxDeltaStep, maxDepth, minChildWeight, missing, normalizeType, nthread, numClass, numEarlyStoppingRounds, numRound, numWorkers, objective, predictionCol, probabilityCol, rateDrop, rawPredictionCol, sampleType, scalePosWeight, seed, silent, sketchEps, skipDrop, subsample, thresholds, timeoutRequestWorkers, trainTestRatio, treeLimit, treeMethod, useExternalMemory, weightCol)
     64 
     65         super(XGBoostClassifier, self).__init__()
---> 66         self._java_obj = self._new_java_obj("ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier", self.uid)
     67         self._create_params_from_java()
     68         self._setDefault()  # We get our defaults from the embedded Scala object, so no need to specify them here.

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p0.6626826/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _new_java_obj(java_class, *args)
     65             java_obj = getattr(java_obj, name)
     66         java_args = [_py2java(sc, arg) for arg in args]
---> 67         return java_obj(*java_args)
     68 
     69     @staticmethod

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I researched about it and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859322/typeerror-javapackage-object-is-not-callable-for-xgboost-in-pyspark) question here that seems to be exaclty the same issue, The user who posted the question also posted the answer and he said the problem was the version of the `sparkxgb.zip` wrapper he was using, that was made for an ancient version of the `xgboost4j` package.

I tried then to look for my correct version of the `sparkxgb.zip` wrapper but after hours of Google i wasn't able to find a site where all the versions were listed indicating for which version of `xgboost4j` they were working. The only i found was standalone links that directly lead to a `sparkxgb.zip` file that i was incapable to figure out if it was the correct for my version of `xgboost4j`.

Could someone tell me if this error i'm getting is related to the `sparkxgb.zip` file? If so, where could i get the right one for `xgboost4j-1.1.2.jar` to use with `Pyspark`? If, the problem was not related to the zip file wrapper, could someone help me in fixing this and make `xgboost4j-1.1.2` work fine for me please?

Thank you very much in advance.