Error when working with geoscan on databricks
I used geoscan libraries on Azure Databricks. However, when I configured for my task, I got this error.
`TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-615568507565679> in <module>
----> 1 gs = Geoscan() \
      2     .setLatitudeCol("latitude") \
      3     .setLongitudeCol("longitude") \
      4     .setPredictionCol("cluster") \
      5     .setEpsilon(400) \

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    112             raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__)
    113         self._input_kwargs = kwargs
--> 114         return func(self, **kwargs)
    115     return wrapper
    116 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geoscan/geoscan.py in __init__(self, epsilon, minPts, predictionCol, latitudeCol, longitudeCol)
    116 
    117         super(Geoscan, self).__init__()
--> 118         self._java_obj = self._new_java_obj(Geoscan._classpath, self.uid)
    119         kwargs = self._input_kwargs
    120         self.setParams(**kwargs)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _new_java_obj(java_class, *args)
     64             java_obj = getattr(java_obj, name)
     65         java_args = [_py2java(sc, arg) for arg in args]
---> 66         return java_obj(*java_args)
     67 
     68     @staticmethod

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`

I have tried like everyone suggested in some other people that also faced my issue, but it doesn't work yet. I want a complete solution for this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/60859322/3238085  The solution here could help you.

You need install Maven package com.databricks.labs:geoscan:0.2.8 along with
the python library.
Refer this documentation for more information.
So, install it in libraries tab.


Can you show me your cluster's config?

What exactly you need in config?
